# C++ rest of my codes aren't loading

Tags: c++

Here's what I have so far. When I compile, I get no errors.

```
 // Sorting Benchmarks
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

 // Function Prototypes
 int bubbleSort (long [], int);
 void showArray (long [], int);

 int main()
 {
     // Define an array with unsorted values
     const int SIZE = 20;
     long values[SIZE] = {20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1};
     int n;

     // Display the values.
    cout << "The unsorted values are\n";
    showArray(values, SIZE);

    // Sort the values using bubble sort
    n = bubbleSort (values, SIZE);

    // Display the number of exchanges while using bubble sort
    cout << n;

    // Display the sorted values.
    cout << "The sorted values are\n";
    showArray (values, SIZE);
    return 0;    
}

int bubbleSort (long array[], int size)
{
    bool swap;
    int temp;
    int exchanges;
    exchanges = 0;
    do
    {
         swap = false;
         for(int count = 0; count < (size - 1); count++)
         {
               if (array[count] > array[count + 1]);
               {
                    array[count + 1] = temp;
                    swap = true;
                    exchanges++;
               }
         }
     }
     while (swap);
     return exchanges;
}

void showArray(long array[], int size)
{
     for(int count = 0; count < size; count++)
     cout << array[count] << " ";
     cout << endl;

     system("PAUSE");
 }
```

The problem is when I run the codes, the only line I get is 
"The unsorted values are
20 19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
Press any key to continue..."

Why won't the rest of codes run after I press any key?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Do you mean in int main? because everything is within {} braces from what I can see....

Answer (score 1):

Your program has an infinite loop because of the `;` at the end of this line:

```
                  if (array[count] > array[count + 1]);
```

Take that out.  Note that your program still has other bugs (your swap is broken).

You might think about switching compilers.  Clang warned on your code even without any special flags:

```
example.cpp:43:59: warning: if statement has empty body [-Wempty-body]
                      if (array[count] > array[count + 1]);
                                                          ^
example.cpp:43:59: note: put the semicolon on a separate line to silence this
      warning
```

Comment: I completely agree the code is broken, but I don't see the infinite loop. I see `swap` is set to false just inside the `do`, we enter a pointless for-loop where `swap` never gets changed because of the bug you id'd, and then the `while(swap)` condition is hit, which breaks the loop.

Comment: @WhozCraig - `swap` *always* gets changed because of the extra `;`.  Everytime through it gets set to true, so the do/while never exits.  The extra `;` is on the `if`, not on the `for`.

Comment: What do you guys mean the code is broken? After removing the semi colon, it fixed the problem I was having. Now I have a fresh new set of problems. When running the code, I have no idea why I'm getting 20 16384 16384 16384.... etc. as my sorted values...

Comment: Yeah, that's why I said it was broken.  And your swap is broken, which is why you get a mess.  Turn on some more compiler warnings (or get a better compiler) and you'll see that `temp` is being used uninitialized.

Answer (score 1):

I think your error is this line:

```
          if (array[count] > array[count + 1]);
```

You probably don't want that semicolon at the end.